# CSocket Server get the client IP Address

Tags: c++, sockets

How can I get the ip address of a client when he tries to connect to the server?
I'm using CSocket class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> void getPeer(unsigned short& port, std::string& peer);
>
> Returns information about the remote
>   side of the socket. port is the port
>   on which the connection is held, and
>   peer is the host to which the socket
>   is connected. The peer is either a
>   fully qualified domain name (if the IP
>   address can be resovled via
>   gethostbyaddr(2) or a stringified
>   dotted IP address if not.

From [here](http://docs.nscl.msu.edu/daq/bluebook/html/r27454.html).

The getPeer function will either return the domain name or the IP address of the remote peer, depending on what it can find.

There appear to be two different definitions of CSocket depending on operating system or library.  If you're using the MFC definition of CSocket then the function you want is actually `getPeerName()` or `getPeerNameEx()` if you're using IP6.  From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hxbew4x(VS.80).aspx):

```
BOOL GetPeerName(
   CString& rPeerAddress,
   UINT& rPeerPort 
);
BOOL GetPeerName(
   SOCKADDR* lpSockAddr,
   int* lpSockAddrLen 
);
```

And from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tefz6a5(VS.80).aspx):

```
BOOL GetPeerNameEx(
   CString& rPeerAddress,
   UINT& rPeerPort 
);
```